# Application with legacy OpenGL recompiled with IVFortran, compiles and links but exits before first executable statement

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, fortran, intel-fortran

The application was previously compiled with CVFortran v6.0 and is now being compiled with IVFortran v11.0 under VisualStudio2008 (to allow use on 64-bit hardware).

There is, potentially, an issue with the legacy OpenGL code in the application but the tools/modules provided with IVF11.0 have enabled the code to recompile and link. When the executable runs it appears to load all the required libraries without any errors and then throws up a command window with the text 'Press any key to continue...'; after a few seconds the program exits (code 0) whether a key is pressed or not.

The main problem is getting a handle on what is going wrong; placing a breakpoint at the first executable statement doesn't trap the problem.

1. Is there a way to trap/investigate errors before the first executable statement?
2. Can someone with experience of similar code/compiler combination point to the likely issue(s)?

Comment: Are you running this inside Visual Studio? That "Press any key to continue" message is displayed when you "Start without debugging" and the program finishes. If you want to debug, set a breakpoint at an early executable line and click Start (or press F5). One thing I have seen is programs which bump up against the 2GB static code/data limit in Windows (even on x64) can have bizarre behavior. If you have large COMMONs or other static arrays, consider making them ALLOCATABLE instead. If you need more help, ask in the Intel Windows Fortran forum. (And maybe get a more recent compiler.)

Comment: Steve, thanks. Maybe i was pressing CTRL-F5 instead of F5. Now I still get a command window but with nothing in it and which seems to prevent any further access to the Visual Studio - and this is still before reaching the breakpoint I have set at the first executable line in WinMain. After about 20-30 sec the command window exits and Visual Studio reports that the code has exited with code 0.

Comment: I just now saw your comment. The only thing I can think of at present is that your breakpoint isn't on an executable line. Is the breakpoint circle solid red or is it a circle with a white center? I do suggest you take this to the Intel forum.